# internal error occurred during: "PHP CodeSniffer". in zend studio 10.0

Tags: php

An internal error occurred during: "PHP CodeSniffer".
org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.PHPLaunchUtilities.getCommandLine(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 3.1.2 release of Eclipse PDT introduced a change that requires the PTI tools to be updated.  The fix is discussed here: https://github.com/pdt-eg/Core-Plugin/issues/22

Unfortunately as of right now there is no PTI update, so unless you are comfortable modifying the plugin yourself you should install the previous version of PDT.