# Eclipse Juno PHP Tools (PTI) Error

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I just found out about PTI (see http://www.phpsrc.org/) but I can't seem to get it to work in Eclipse Juno.

I also have PDT installed, with my PHP Executables, PHP Interpreter, and Execution Environments all set up under my workspace preferences. Each PHP Tools feature I want to use is configured to use the PHP Executable and PEAR library I have set up.

When I try to run any of the tools (PHP CodeSniffer, PHP Copy/Paste Detector, PHP Depend, PHPUnit, or PHPMD), I get an alert that say the following:

```
'PHP Depend' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "PHP Depend".

Details >>
An internal error occurred during: "PHP Depend".
org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.PHPLaunchUtilities.getCommandLine(
   Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;
   Ljava/lang/String;
   Ljava/lang/String;
   Ljava/lang/String;
   [Ljava/lang/String;
)[Ljava/lang/String;
```

Has anyone been able to get this awesome tool to work on Juno? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Downgrading PDT from version 3.2.1 to 3.0.0 (installed from General Tools of 'Indigo') sorted out the problem for me. It works now fine.

I checked many possible workarounds (begin of path here: [internal error occurred during: "PHP CodeSniffer". in zend studio 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954132/internal-error-occurred-during-php-codesniffer-in-zend-studio-10-0) ) but just above solution gave results.